# Why is my ModelState null when running a unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381448/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-is-null-in-my-unit-test-why) and tried the solution and it did not work for me.  I am trying to understand this and perhaps I am not testing this properly.  I am getting a `NullReferenceException` on the line in the controller where I am testing ModelState.  I am using MVC 3 with NUnit as my test suite.  `ShouldBeViewNamed("Index")` is an extension method I wrote to test the Name of the view I am getting back, but I don't even get that far when executing the code.  Here is my controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) // results in a null reference exception.
            return View();

        return new ViewResult();
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestControllerTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestingModelState()
    {
        // Arrange
        var model = new TestModel();
        var controller = new TestController();
        // Arbitrary values to indicate an error in the model
        controller.ModelState.AddModelError("tester1", "error happened"); 

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index(model);

        // Assert
        result.ShouldBeViewNamed("Index");
    }
}
```

According to most blogs that I've read, this should "just work".  But no matter what I do, the ModelState is always null...  If this works for someone else, I'll assume it has to do with my local setup or perhaps a framework we use.  I have had one other developer test this at my shop and he also gets the same exception.

**EDIT**:  I have narrowed down the issue to being specific to this particular project.  By adding a new project to the solution and testing with the same tests, I cannot duplicate this issue.  Needless to say this is an inherited project that was started in 2009 likely as an MVC 1 project and has been upgraded to MVC 3.  I will look at project level settings next.

**EDIT**:  See the answer below, turns out a consultant we had hired a while back attempted to upgrade the project to MVC 4, ran into some issues and never reverted the files.  Most of the unit tests still passed and the projects ran fine, but the NUnit project had a bad reference to MVC 4.  I had to manually delete the reference from the `.csproj` file and readd it in VS and everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your NUnit project is referencing the same version of System.Web.Mvc.dll as your MVC project.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I literally just discovered this about 10 minutes ago and was writing up an answer when I saw your post.

Comment: I have lost a day trying to find a solution for this. Thank you for this answer.